# JQuery Ignore element values in hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I ignore elements in hidden div? I have a form with visible elements and some elements that are hidden in a div...

```
<form id="my-form">
  <input name="split_values[]" class="split">
  <input name="split_values[]" class="split">
  <input name="split_values[]" class="split">
  <div class="hidden-div">
    <input name="split_values[]" class="split">
  </div>
</form>
```

I am lopping through the elements for validation...

```
$('#my-form *').filter(':input').each(function(){ 
  // my validation here
});
```

But I want to ignore any values that are in a hidden div. So I want to only see validation for the first 3 elements and not the fourth one in the hidden div. As the elements are dynamically generated its not possible for me to give them ids.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if (!$(this).parent().hasClass(".hidden-div")) ...`  You can also target direct descendants only: `$("#my-form > input")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo-selector to filter out hidden `input`-fields:

```
$('#my-form *').filter(':input:visible').each(function() {
   // my validation here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure your structure will not change, you could use

```
$('#my-form>input')
```

wich should get only the inputs which are immediate children of the form, excluding the divs.

```
$('#my-form>:not(.hidden-div)')
```

this would get all children of my-form that are not of class hidden-div

Answer (score 0):

Apply a not function with a selector of the div class

```
$('#my-form *').not('.hidden-div').filter(':input').each(function(){ 
  // my validation here
});
```

Comment: The class is in the parent element.

Comment: Changed it to put not on the form

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my-form *').filter(':input').each(function(){ 
 if(!$(this.parentElement).hasClass('hidden-div')){
  console.log(this);
 }
});
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe in working example, here it is.

```js
console.log($('#my-form .split:not(.hidden-div .split)').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
<input name="split_values[]" class="split">
<input name="split_values[]" class="split">
<input name="split_values[]" class="split">
<div class="hidden-div">
<input name="split_values[]" class="split">
</div>
</form>
```